JavaFX TableView populating columns with same value 3 times
I have this bit of code for setting up a TableView
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        if(App.Customers.get(App.currentcustomerindex).getAccounts().get(App.currentaccountindex).getAccounttype().equalsIgnoreCase("tmb")||App.Customers.get(App.currentcustomerindex).getAccounts().get(App.currentaccountindex).getAccounttype().equalsIgnoreCase("gold")){
            Checking workchecking = (Checking) App.Customers.get(App.currentcustomerindex).getAccounts().get(App.currentaccountindex);
            String Balance = Double.toString(workchecking.getBalance());
            String Dateopened = workchecking.getDateopened().toString();
            String Savingsid = workchecking.getSavingsaccountid();
            ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            list.addAll(Balance,Dateopened,Savingsid);
            tablebox.setItems(list);
            TableColumn<String,String> column1 = new TableColumn<String,String>("Balance");
            column1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(Balance));
            TableColumn<String,String> column2= new TableColumn<>("Date Opened");
            column2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(Dateopened));
            TableColumn<String,String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Savings ID");
            column3.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(Savingsid));
            tablebox.getColumns().setAll(column1,column2,column3);
        }
    }

Which produces the following TableView:

So any idea what I am doing wrong here? I have also tried cellData.getValue() in place of Balance, DateOpened and SavingsID in the SimpleStringProperty with the same results.I would like the data to only display in the first row..

It look like you're creating a new StringProperty each time the factory is called. Instead, reuse a single instance, for example.

The first thing you need to fix is your use of a TableView<String>.  Each row of your table represents a Checking instance, so you should create a TableView<Checking>. The items in that table should be Checking objects, not strings.
Collection<Checking> workchecking =
    App.Customers.get(App.currentcustomerindex).getAccounts();

tablebox.getItems().setAll(workchecking);

You have multiple Checking records, so reading the balance, date, and ID at this time is meaningless.  Don’t read any of them when creating the table.  Instead, read those values only when the TableColumn asks for them, which it will do by calling your cell value factories.
The whole point of a cell value factory is that it retrieves the values of the record at a requested row.  Which row, you might ask?  The row specified in the CellDataFeatures which is passed to the cell value factory.
So, you can just write:
TableColumn<Checking, String> balanceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Balance");
balanceColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
        String.valueOf(cellData.getValue().getBalance())));

TableColumn<Checking, String> dateColumn = new TableColumn<>("Date Opened");
column2.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
        String.valueOf(cellData.getValue().getDateopened())));

TableColumn<Checking, String> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("Savings ID");
column3.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
        cellData.getValue().getSavingsaccountid()));

tablebox.getColumns().add(balanceColumn);
tablebox.getColumns().add(dateColumn);
tablebox.getColumns().add(idColumn);

In each of the above cell value factories, cellData.getValue() provides the Checking object at the row whose values the TableView is about to display.  That is the entire point of the CellDataFeatures object.
trashgod has already linked to an explanation of why you should never use PropertyValueFactory.  To summarize:  it’s easy to make mistakes with PropertyValueFactory, and neither the compiler nor PropertyValueFactory will tell you when you’ve made such a mistake.  Instead, write your own cell value factories, like above;  the compiler can check them for correctness.
Formatting
To go a step farther:  you should not turn all of your data into strings.  A TableView lets a user sort by columns, but because your values are strings, it would sort 155.28 before a value like 19.10. This happens because they are being ordered by their characters, not their numeric values.
You can solve this by making your cell value factory return raw data, while having the cell factory (not the cell value factory) format the data for display.  This works because a TableView sorts based on raw data (obtained from cell value factories), not on how the data is displayed.
To do this, assign the actual data types to each column:
TableColumn<Checking, Double> balanceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Balance");
balanceColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleDoubleProperty(
        cellData.getValue().getBalance()));

TableColumn<Checking, LocalDate> dateColumn = new TableColumn<>("Date Opened");
column2.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(
        cellData.getValue().getDateopened()));

TableColumn<Checking, String> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("Savings ID");
column3.setCellValueFactory(
    cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
        cellData.getValue().getSavingsaccountid()));

tablebox.getColumns().add(balanceColumn);
tablebox.getColumns().add(dateColumn);
tablebox.getColumns().add(idColumn);

Notice the use of TableColumn<Checking, Double> and TableColumn<Checking, LocalDate>, to indicate the type of data displayed in each of those columns.  Also notice the use of SimpleDoubleProperty and SimpleObjectProperty, instead of SimpleStringProperty.
To get them to display in a certain format, create a single formatting object and use it in a cell factory (which is not the same as a cell value factory):
NumberFormat balanceFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

balanceColumn.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<Checking, Double>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Double balance,
                              boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(balance, empty);

        setGraphic(null);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(balanceFormat.format(balance));
        }
    }
});

It is vital that a cell factory both calls super.updateItem and properly handles the empty and null cases properly.  The documentation of Cell.updateItem explains this in detail.
You seem to be content with your dates displaying in their default (ISO 8601) format.  If you wanted them to be localized, you could do the same for dates as the above code does for balance values:
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter =
    DateTimeformatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);

dateColumn.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<Checking, LocalDate>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDate date,
                              boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(date, empty);

        setGraphic(null);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(dateFormatter.format(date));
        }
    }
});

Again, the benefit of doing this is that the TableView will sort dates in chronological order, not alphabetical order.

Thank you for the in depth response, I am learning a lot about Javafx in quite a short time period. The currency instance is particularly helpful.

I do have one question, what is the item variable referring to in the setText part of the code? When I use it the IDE just tells me to make a local variable

Never mind, just had to put the input variable in instead of item

now my problem is I am using a single ComboBox to switch between three different subclasses, so the get methods are not the same for each subclass. I am listing Savings, Checking, and Loan types all in a single ComboBox of type Account

@ThomasHutton Since a ComboBox can only display one type, and that type cannot be changed, I recommend making three ComboBox instances, one for each type.  Place all of them in a single StackPane and pass true to the setVisible method of the one you want to display, and call setVisible(false) on the ones you don’t want displayed.

that is actually exactly what I ended up doing! thank you for the answer. I did not set them in a StackPane though (they are just attached the the window anchor pane on top of each other) we are running out of time on this project so I may do that if we finish everything else

Figured it out with this:
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        if(App.Customers.get(App.currentcustomerindex).getAccounts().get(App.currentaccountindex).getAccounttype().equalsIgnoreCase("tmb")||App.Customers.get(App.currentcustomerindex).getAccounts().get(App.currentaccountindex).getAccounttype().equalsIgnoreCase("gold")){
            Checking workchecking = (Checking) App.Customers.get(App.currentcustomerindex).getAccounts().get(App.currentaccountindex);
            String Balance = Double.toString(workchecking.getBalance());
            String Dateopened = workchecking.getDateopened().toString();
            String Savingsid = workchecking.getSavingsaccountid();
            ObservableList<Checking> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            list.addAll(workchecking);
            tablebox.setItems(list);
            TableColumn<Checking,Double> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Balance");
            column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("balance"));
            TableColumn<Checking,LocalDate> column2= new TableColumn<>("Date Opened");
            column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateopened"));
            TableColumn<Checking,String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("Savings ID");
            column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("savingsaccountid"));
            tablebox.getColumns().setAll(column1,column2,column3);
        }
    }

values in PropertyValueFactory are names of the relevant attributes from the Checking class

For a better alternative, see _Why should I avoid using PropertyValueFactory in JavaFX?

Thanks for the answer, having to learn on the fly for this and seeing a lot of bad responses out there apparently
